# Calculated Fields - Time in to percentage

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on a calculated field but hitting a bit of a wall.

I have in my table a column with times in and in my calculated field I want to convert the time to a percentage based on a target time.

Example:

My table has the time 22:00 (22 minutes)
Target time is 25:00 (25 minutes)

In my expression builder I am using the following:

```
=[time]/00:25:00
```

but this is not giving the results I need

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert to a number, say, Double:

```
=CDbl([time)/CDbl(#00:25:00#)
```